# mineral prospecting in Iran

Tags: mineralogy

I live in Iran and I want to do personal mineral prospecting for natural crystals and gemstones and beautiful minerals. Unfortunately, there are no 
reliable information available. Anyone can help me where to start and any information about interesting site/spots?

Comment: you need to get a geological map of your area(there is lots of them online),use the maps to learn about what types of minerals you can expect to find in combination with the  minerals in your area.it does not look like you have done a good job searching the net for information about your area.

Comment: Get in touch with other mineral collectors in Iran. There must be plenty of them, just as there are in most other countries. They could give you a few tips about where to look.